# How to generate QR code of an image in Android?

Tags: java, android, image, qr-code

How to generate QR code of an image in android using Java, so that when I scan the QR code and in output it will give an image? Neither I want to embed any URL of the image in the QR nor want to save the image over any server or cloud and then fetch it from there to view it. Kindly tell me any other alternative, like Scanova is doing the same but their API is not free. What I want that how did they do it, they are creating a QR of an image, and when someone scans it they will get an image as output.

Comment: https://github.com/kenglxn/QRGen

Comment: You seem to be assuming that all QR code scanners would know how to interpret such a QR code. My guess is that very few will, as I do not see much in the way of standards for encoding an image into a QR code. If you find a QR code that works the way you want with some QR code scanner, you may be able to reverse engineer what the encoding format is. Perhaps they are using a `data` URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this library that generate QR codes from images.
https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner

I hope to help you.

Comment: I don't want the image between the center of QR code, want to embed an image in the QR code